# Unable to autoscroll JavaScript slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a pure JavaScript slider which automatically scrolls as the page loads. The slider gets successfully triggered for the first time and here comes the issue. When this slider goes through `setInterval()` function for the second iteration, the list items gets undefined (ie: *the value of 'i'*). Also I want the slider to autoscroll. I need this to get done with the help of **pure JavaScript**. Here is my code,

JS:

```
    function slider() {

        var ul = document.getElementById("imageSlider");
        var liItems = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var imageWidth = liItems[0].offsetWidth;
        var imageNumber = liItems.length;
        setInterval(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i <= liItems.length; i++) {

                liItems[i].style.right = liItems[i].style.right + imageWidth + 'px';
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

CSS:

```
    .slider-wrapper {
        height: 115px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .slide-wrapper {
        height: 95px;
        width: 274px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(#aaaaaa,#e2e2e2);
        background-size: auto 200%;
        background-position: 0 100%;
        transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .slide-wrapper:hover {
            height: 95px;
            width: 274px;
            background-position: 0 0;
        }
    .slide {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .image {
        text-align: center;
        height: 95px;
        width: 274px;
        line-height: 92px;
    }

    .image-style {
        max-width: 150px;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 75px;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .left-arrow {
        width: 75px;
        height: 115px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
        font-size: 75px;
    }

    .right-arrow {
        width: 75px;
        height: 115px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
        font-size: 75px;
    }

    .image-slider-ul {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .container-middle {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 115px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1188px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <body onload="slider()">
        <ul id="imageSlider" class="image-slider-ul">
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div class="left-arrow">&lt;</div>
                <div class="container-middle">
                    <li class="slide"><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div></div></li>
                    <li class="slide"><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div></div></li>
                    <li class="slide"><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/3-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div></div></li>
                    <li class="slide"><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/4-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div></div></li>
                    <li class="slide"><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/5-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div></div></li>
                </div>
                <div class="right-arrow">&gt;</div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Please help me figure this out! Thankyou..

Comment: Change the loop to for (var i = 0; i <= liItems.length - 1; i++) {

Comment: @Velko Tried but still the problem persists :(

Comment: If you substract 1 to the length the undefined error should not appear any more, nevertheless the autoscroll will stop because you haven't implemented the case when the end is reached. Do you still get the undefined error or the scroll stops ?

Comment: This makes me get rid of the undefined error. Thankyou. But need my slider to autoscroll

Comment: Your question was how to fix the undefined error, and not how to implement the rest of the sliders logic :)

Comment: I was to mention both the issues but unfortunately didn't mention the latter. Now I have mentioned that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we could make it automatic left sliding when periodical change of `img element src` with help of `setInterval()`.

**code:**

```js
function slider() {
    // var ul = document.getElementById("imageSlider");
    // var liItems = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    // var imageWidth = liItems[0].offsetWidth;
    // var imageNumber = liItems.length;
    setInterval(function() {
       var souc = document.getElementsByClassName("image-style");
       var firstSrc = souc[0].src
      for (var i = 0; i < souc.length -1; i++) {
        souc[i].src = souc[i+1].src;
      }
      souc[souc.length-1].src = firstSrc;
    }, 2000);
  }
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
        height: 115px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .slide-wrapper {
        height: 95px;
        width: 274px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(#aaaaaa,#e2e2e2);
        background-size: auto 200%;
        background-position: 0 100%;
        transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .slide-wrapper:hover {
            height: 95px;
            width: 274px;
            background-position: 0 0;
        }
    .slide {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .image {
        text-align: center;
        height: 95px;
        width: 274px;
        line-height: 92px;
    }

    .image-style {
        max-width: 150px;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 75px;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .left-arrow {
        width: 75px;
        height: 115px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
        font-size: 75px;
    }

    .right-arrow {
        width: 75px;
        height: 115px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
        font-size: 75px;
    }

    .image-slider-ul {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .container-middle {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 115px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1188px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="slider()">
  <div>
  <ul id="imageSlider" class="image-slider-ul">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="left-arrow">&lt;</div>
      <div class="container-middle">
        <li class="slide">
          <div class="slide-wrapper">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
          <div class="slide-wrapper">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
          <div class="slide-wrapper">
            <div class="image"><img  src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/3-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
          <div class="slide-wrapper">
            <div class="image"><img  src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/4-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
          <div class="slide-wrapper">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/5-Number-PNG.png" class="image-style"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="right-arrow">&gt;</div>
    </div>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Note:**
open snippet in full page, you can understand clearly.

l hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your problem arises as the first iteration moves elements to right but then does not repeat themselves as there are no elements to the left.

You could try to create a function which will move back all elements to the original position at the `elements.lenth` loop iteration as you'll be showing the animation to the last element as well.